# How to provide a default typeclass for generic types in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, types, typeclass, type-parameter

In Scala, if you create a typeclass, say the algebraic structure `Monoid[T]`, you can provide many default typeclass implementations for different types that are monoids.

Suppose a monoid is defined as:

```
trait Monoid[T] {
  def op(x: T, y: T): T
  def id: T
}
```

Since `String`s under the concatenation operation form a monoid, we can provide a default monoid for `String`s like this:

```
implicit object StringMonoid extends Monoid[String] {
  override def op(a: String, b: String): String = a + b
  override def id: String = ""
}
```

This is rather easy, since `String` is not a generic type.

What I am asking for is **how to provide a default monoid for `Seq[T]`s**, in which the type parameter prevents me from creating an implicit object like I did above.

I could do:

```
class SeqMonoid[T] extends Monoid[Seq[T]] {
  override def op(a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = a ++ b
  override def id: Seq[T] = Nil
}
implicit object intSeqMonoid extends SeqMonoid[Int]
implicit object doubleSeqMonoid extends SeqMonoid[Double]
implicit object stringSeqMonoid extends SeqMonoid[String]
...
```

But this approach doesn't utilize the beauty of generic types.

So, in general, my question is: Is there any way in Scala I can provide **typeclass implementations for generic types**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide an implicit function with the required type:

```
implicit def SeqMonoid[T]: Monoid[Seq[T]] = new Monoid[Seq[T]] {
  override def op(a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = a ++ b
  override def id: Seq[T] = Nil
}
```

Comment: Won't this create a new object every time a `Monoid[Seq[T]]` is needed?

Comment: @YuhuanJiang Yes, but you don't really have a choice if you want it to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

Variation without repeating `Seq[T]`:

```
object Monoid {
  implicit def seqMonoid[T]:Monoid[Seq[T]] = {
    type S = Seq[T]
    new Monoid[S] {
     def op(x: S, y: S) = x ++ y
     def id = Nil
    }
  }
}
```