# Why does + operator on parameterized types in scala always result in string

Tags: java, scala

Consider a class as follows:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{HashMap => MutableHashMap}
class CustomHashMap[K,V](hashMap: MutableHashMap[K,V], initVal: V) {
  def addMaps(first: MutableHashMap[K, V], second: MutableHashMap[K, V]): MutableHashMap[K, V] = {
    second.foreach(pair => { first += (pair._1 -> (first.getOrElse(pair._1, initVal) + pair._2)) } )
    //The above line throws a compile time error
    first
  }
  //Other functions
}
```

Upon adding the two parameterized types there is a compile time error saying

```
expected (K,V) recieved (K,String)
```

I want to know why does scala do this implicit conversion? Since operator overloading was not allowed in java this seemed logical but in case of scala V could actually be a class that could have a method `+` defined for it.

Comment: Scala is not a duck-typed language.

Comment: `V` *could be a class that has a method `+`*, but there is no guarantee that it will! It *could be* something else.

Comment: @m-z So there is no method through which such a functionality can be achieved in scala?

Comment: It's not clear what you're after. Should `V` be numeric? Or just have a `+` method? Either way it will need some constraint like a structural type, or a type class.

Comment: Any class that has a plus method and whose `+` method returns an instance of itself. I personally required only numeric types but I was thinking if something generic could be written using templates.

Comment: Sounds like you want a monoid. And in this code you are actually trying to define the monoid for maps (the result of your code is conceptually the same as what scalaz would do in `first |+| second`, but you use mutable maps and require to provide the monoid's zero for each operation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way how to implement this kind of thing manually:

Since it looks like you are trying to define a monoid I'll take the liberty to move `initVal` from `addMaps` to the definition of the operation.

This can be done with the common typeclass pattern in Scala, but you'll have to define manually what `+` means for each type, you want to use in your map.

Basically you have a trait `Monoid`:

```
trait Monoid[T] {
  def mzero: T                        // your initVal
  def madd(first: T, second: T): T    // the + operation
}
```

Than you define implicit implementations for each type extending that trait. You can define them in

- the companion object of `Monoid`, it'll be used automatically,
- the companion object of class T, it'll also be used automatically,
- as an implicit somewhere else, but you'll have to import it manually.

Here's an example of `Monoid` companion object defining implementations for strings and all kinds of numbers:

```
object Monoid {
  implicit object StringMonoid extends Monoid[String] {
    def mzero = ""
    def madd(first: String, second: String) = first + second
  }

  implicit def NumericMonoid[T](implicit ev: Numeric[T]): Monoid[T] = 
    new Monoid[T] {
      import Numeric.Implicits._

      def mzero = ev.zero
      def madd(first: T, second: T) = first + second
    }
}
```

Then in your `addMaps` function request that elements of the maps should be `Monoid`s, and use operations provided by the monoid implementation on the elements:

```
def addMaps[K, V](first: MutableHashMap[K, V], second: MutableHashMap[K, V])
                 (implicit ev: Monoid[V]): MutableHashMap[K, V] = {
  second.foreach { pair => 
    first += (pair._1 -> ev.madd(first.getOrElse(pair._1, ev.mzero), pair._2)) }
  first
}
```

And here's a test how it works:

```
scala> addMaps(MutableHashMap(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4), MutableHashMap(1 -> 3, 5 -> 7))
res1: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(5 -> 7, 1 -> 5, 3 -> 4)

scala> addMaps(MutableHashMap(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar"), MutableHashMap(1 -> "baz", 3 -> "qoo"))
res2: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,String] = Map(2 -> bar, 1 -> foobaz, 3 -> qoo)
```

Comment: I guess I would have to understand some scala before I can mark this as right 0.o

Comment: @Sohaib Basically Monoid is the same thing as Adder from the other answer, but with its own initVal. You can use the same practices: e.g., implicit parameters and implementations in companion objects to implement Adder. Also, please, don't hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: I understand the trait Monoid. What I don't understand is the object Monoid. Specifically the StringMonoid and the NumericMonoid. Why is one an object and the other a method? I know how an implicit method like `stringWrapper(s: String): RichString` works. I did not ask because I thought these may be specific language constructs that I yet don't understand and it would be better that I search them up separately rather than ask here.

Comment: @Sohaib When Scala looks for an implicit parameter, it also tries to find implicit conversions to the required type. And so to define an implementation of a typeclass for a whole range of types with some constraints (e.g., `[A <: Base]`, `[A : Ordering]`, `Seq[A]`, etc.), you have to do it as a function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680206/how-to-provide-a-default-typeclass-for-generic-types-in-scala/30680428 (it's also about monoids :-) But for `String`, you don't need that, you can provide a simple implicit `object` or `val`.

Comment: @Sohaib So this implementation with `Numeric` would work for `Int`, `Double`, `Long`, `BigInt`, `BigDecimal` and whatever else has implementation of typeclass `Numeric`. (But combining types, e.g.,  `first: Map[A, Int]`, `second: Map[A, Double]` and the result `Map[A, Double]` is more complex).

Comment: Thanks for the patience in explaining everything.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is because you are trying to do `V + V` and Scala is inferring type `V` to be a String. Here is my attempt to specify to the compiler that `V` will extend a trait (called `Adder`) that will support a `V + V => V`.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{HashMap => MutableHashMap}

trait Adder[A]{
    def +(b: A): A
}

class CustomHashMap[K, V <: Adder[V]](hashMap: MutableHashMap[K,V], initVal: V) {

  def addMaps(first: MutableHashMap[K, V], second: MutableHashMap[K, V]): MutableHashMap[K, V] = {
    second.foreach(pair => { first += (pair._1 -> (first.getOrElse[V](pair._1, initVal) + pair._2)) } )
    first
  }
  //Other functions ...
}
```

The above solution will require `V` to extend `Adder`. If we want to make this easier to user, we can use implicit conversions. In order for you to add custom types, you need to bring an implicit conversion to the scope (similar to what we did with Int, String, and Double).

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{HashMap => MutableHashMap}

trait Adder[A]{
  def add(x:A, y: A): A
}

implicit object IntAdder extends Adder[Int] {
  def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
}

implicit object StringAdder extends Adder[String] {
  def add(x: String, y: String): String = x + y
}

implicit object DoubleAdder extends Adder[Double] {
  def add(x: Double, y: Double): Double = x + y
}

class CustomHashMap[K, V](hashMap: MutableHashMap[K,V], initVal: V)(implicit m: Adder[V]) {

  def addMaps(first: MutableHashMap[K, V], second: MutableHashMap[K, V]): MutableHashMap[K, V] = {
    second.foreach(pair => { first += (pair._1 -> m.add( first.getOrElse[V](pair._1, initVal), pair._2)) } )
    first
  }
  //Other functions ...
}
```

Comment: So any object that does not use the trait adder cannot be used with this class?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about  the same thing ... One idea is to have an implicit conversion that will know how to convert from some type X to A. So you can have default implementations for things like Int, Long, String, Double. For any custom type, I guess you do need to provide an `+` function.

Comment: Can you add that to the answer in a little more verbose manner? :)

Comment: Will do ... But I have to be out for the next hour or so :(. I hope u can wait until then ...

Comment: I added what I had in mind as an alternative solution. Hmm, just noticed that the second solution is very similar to what @Kolmar has. I guess this is a good solution too.

Comment: Yes this is very similar to @Kolmar although I like his solution better now that I understand it. Thanks for the help. I will wait for some more votes before I mark an answer as correct.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html) for the documentation of both solutions. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to marios' answer, you might want to use a functional programming library that gives you already the type-classes `Semigroup` (addition) or `Monoid` (addition and empty element).

For example with [Cats](https://github.com/non/cats):

```
scala> import cats.Monoid

scala> def joinMaps[K, V](a: Map[K, V], b: Map[K, V])(implicit m: Monoid[V]) =
  b.foldLeft(a) { case (res, (k, v)) => 
    res + (k -> m.combine(res.getOrElse(k, m.empty), v)) 
  }
```

To test:

```
scala> import cats.std.list._  // has a Monoid for List

scala> joinMaps(Map("a" -> List(1, 2), "b" -> List(3, 4)), 
                Map("b" -> List(5, 6), "c" -> List(7, 8)))
res1: Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(a -> List(1, 2), b -> List(3, 4, 5, 6),
                                  c -> List(7, 8))
```

In general, it makes your code more modular if you separate the addition function into a type-class (here the `Monoid`) instead of requiring it to be part of your value type `V <: Adder`.